Dragging Google Chrome window to resize does not work when using system title bars and borders
This happens with several apps like telegram, google chrome, postman and more. If they are using the "System Title and Border" option, I am unable to drag them to resize but clicking and holding on the corners of the window. If I disable this option, they work.
This is only happening currently with Ubuntu 24.04.
For the borders, I mean this, here is Google Chrome with what they call "Use System title bar and borders":

But if I remove the border like so it works:

Is there a hidden setting I am unaware of that is affecting this behavior. This could maybe be related to another issue where I can not copy an image to clipboard and paste it in Chrome.
BUG REPORTS:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/2064177

Please close, a bug report was found here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/2064177
